# Изменить свойство объекта в коллекции TabPage

Tags: c#, winforms

Необходимо было сделать список изображений, чтобы они переключались через `TabPages`. 
В каждом `TabPage` добавляю объект `PictureBox`. 
Затем необходимо по нажатии клавиши открыть в другой форме увеличенный размер картинки, а для этого нужно получить свойство PictureBox.Image в коллекции `TabPage.Controls`. Как это можно сделать?

```
pictureBox1 = new PictureBox { BackColor = Color.White };
pictureBox1.Size = new Size(tabPage1.Size.Width, tabPage1.Size.Height);
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;

tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.SelectedIndex].Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
if (Clipboard.GetImage() != null)
{
    //Выводим изображение на pictureBox
    pictureBox1.Image = Clipboard.GetImage();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Нужно хранить картинки в списке, список использовать в TabPages и в другой форме.

Comment: Просто нужно тогда связать соответствующую картинку с соответствующим индексом `TabPage`. Нужно тогда создавать список из 2 элементов - индекса TabPage и самой картинки? Просто, мне кажется, это слишком неправильно.

Comment: + мы же заносим объект `PictureBox` в `TabPages`. А значит и доступ к его свойствам после можем получить из коллекции.

Comment: Картинки в списке должны быть в таком порядке, в котором добавляются в TabPages. Т.е. по индексу TabPage можно будет получить картинку из списка.

Comment: Понял, попробую сделать так, спасибо.

Comment: А почему нельзя в самом TabPage в событии OnClick запускать форму с изображением? Могу оформить ответ если требуется

Comment: Во избежание лишних нажатий на изображение, сделал отдельно кнопку